# C# WCF Service, read soapenv header security section

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, header

I'm looking for a workaround fix to read out the incoming soapenv => Security section.

I've been trying to get the soapenv from the incoming request, but with no luck:

```
int operationIndex = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.FindHeader("Security", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
string operation = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.GetHeader<string>(operationIndex);
```

This is an example on how the header is formatted :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
  <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1">
            <wsse:Username>TheUsername</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">XXXXXXXXXXXXX</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>XXXXXXXXXX</wsu:Created>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:AMethod>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:field>2</tem:field>
      </tem:AMethod>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Is there any other way that i could read the incoming soapheader?

**Edit**

Did just found another way to get the soapheader

```
var headerContent = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.Select((value, i) => new { i, value }).ToList().Where(x => x.value.Name.ToLower().Equals("security")).FirstOrDefault();
XmlDictionaryReader xr = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.GetReaderAtHeader(headerContent.i);
string xmlSecurityHeader = xr.ReadOuterXml();
```

Comment: What do you mean with no luck? Is the operation index -1 or something else? The `IncomingMessageHeaders` implements `IEnumerable`. Have you tried to enumerate all of the headers to see what's in there?

Comment: I just found another way to get the related header :
`code`
var headerContent = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.Select((value, i) => new { i, value }).ToList().Where(x => x.value.Name.ToLower().Equals("security")).FirstOrDefault();
            XmlDictionaryReader xr = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.GetReaderAtHeader(headerContent.i);
            string xmlSecurityHeader = xr.ReadOuterXml()
`code`

Answer (score 1):

You can try messageinspector, Implement the IClientMessageInspector interface on the client side, and implement the IDispatchMessageInspector interface on the server side. You can intercept requests and replies.

Here is the sample on the client:

```
     public class ClientMessageLogger : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        string outputstr = $"Server reply message received by the client:\n{reply}\n";
        Console.WriteLine(outputstr);
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        string outputText = $"The request message that the client will send:\n{request}\n";
        Console.WriteLine(outputText);
        return null;

    }
}
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface)]
public class CustomBehavior : Attribute, IContractBehavior
{
    public Type TargetContract => typeof(ServiceReference1.ICalculator);
    public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        return;
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(new ClientMessageLogger());
    }
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
    {
        return;
    }

    public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Here is the sample on the server:

```
public class CustomMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            string displayText = $"The request message received by the server:\n{request}\n";
            Console.WriteLine(displayText);
            return null;
        }

        public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            string displayText = $"Server reply message:\n{reply}\n";
            Console.WriteLine(displayText);
        }
    }
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface)]
    public class CustomBehavior : Attribute, IContractBehavior
    {
        public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
            return;
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
            return;
        }
        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
        {
            dispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new CustomMessageInspector());
        }

        public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Eventually, add the `[CustomBehavior]` above the interface, On the client, the interface is in your service reference.